# Nintex forms for Office 365 - Error in new NF.PeoplePickerAPI method

Tags: office365, nintex-workflow, peoplepicker

Community,

I am attempting to create a new instance of the NF.PeoplePickerApi in Javascript on a Nintex for Office 365 form.

```
try{
    var insEmployeeName = new NF.PeoplePickerApi('.EmployeeName input'); //ERROR!
    insEmployeeName.added(function(){
        alert('New name added.');
    });
}
catch(error){
    alert('Error adding change event to people picker: ' + error.message);
}
```

However, I encounter the error "Object doesn't support the action" on the line where I "new up" the object.

In the debugger I can see that the NF object doesn't have a PeoplePickerApi method.  The problem is this was working code in the on-premise version of the product.  I suspect this is a shortcoming of the Office 365 version.  Sadly, I can find no alternative. Has anyone encountered or overcome this issue?

Comment: were you able to do it? I am also facing the same issue, but no resolution from anywhere